# how to make form action change hash and not reload page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, hash

I have a website that has dynamic data and it is based on the data after the '#' when I change it in the URL my website does not reload, but when I change it in the form it reloads the webpage...

how can I make it so that it just chagnes the value after the # without reloading the page?

```
<div id="but1">
 <form action="http://website.com/#800" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>       
</div>
```

can I have it call a javascript function on form action? How would I do that?

Comment: Do you want to actually submit the form to a server? if so look into ajax requests... or if you just want to do some processing in client side, you can change it using javascript... can you be more specific and add such information..? cause " that has dynamic data" is very vague... how it's added, where does it come from...

Comment: What JavaScript have you currently got? Please include it above.

Comment: calling JS from form on submit:  `<form action="javascript:alert('action sent');" >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the onsubmit attribute in html to call a function list this:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction(); return false;">
```

Or you can bind an on submit function using jquery like this:

```
$('form').submit(myFunction);
```

If you are looking to process the data on your server, you can use the JQuery ajax method to send data to another page asynchronously.

Comment: this seems to work - I can have it call my javascript function, but the page then seems to redirect to the main page

<div id="but1">
 <form onsubmit="scroll(400)" >
<input type="submit" value="But1">
          </form>  
</div>

Comment: The problem is that the form is still submitting after it runs the code. If you add a "return false" after the onsubmit attribute, it will prevent this. I have updated my original answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

this might help:

```
<form action="javascript:window.location.hash = 'tada'; return false;">
  <!-- just set the hash /-->
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

but i think you want to fire a javascript also?

```
<form action="#tada" onsubmit="something;">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is change the hash, don't POST. Try something like this:

```
<form action="#800" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

A simple link like `<a href="#800">Submit</a>` would have the same effect as well.

Comment: this is on a joomla cms site, and when I do that it seems to redirect to the home page